# New App - Build SDK Android 2.2 (API 8) not available. How to make it show up?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to build a project at minimum Android 2.2 (API 8) for my Android 3.1 device. However, "Android 2.2 (API 8)" was not one of the options on the list. It only presented 3 options: Android v2.1, v4.0, and v4.0.3. The first one was too low for my project while the next 2 were too high for my device.

[image]

I checked to make sure that I already installed Android 2.2 in the SDK Manager.

[image]

So, how do I make "Android 2.2 (API 8)" become an option for my project? I must be missing something very simple. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can choose API 7 in the wizard and manually change `android:minSdkVersion` to `8` in your Manifest later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double check your PATH to sdk, which SDK it's pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

I would check your /android-sdk-xxxx/platforms folder. You should have in there a folder called /android-8

If this is not present, you may not have it actually installed. Try to re-install and restart the AVD.

Here is a copy to place in your /platforms folder if that still does not work. 
http://www.sendspace.com/file/21r31h

Comment: Thank you. I had the android-8 folder inside the platforms folder, but I didn't realize that the Eclipse was pointing to a different location. After fixing up the path, I were able to select API-8 for my new project.